# 500 server error on return object of a class

Tags: php, oop, symfony

I tried a lot but no result:-

Create Form Response Function:

```
public static $codes= array('error1','error2','error3');

public static function createFromResponse($response)
{        
    $code = $response->body->category_code; //it contains the values from $codes array

    if (isset(self::$codes[$code])){
        $cn = self::$codes[$code];
    }
    else{
        $cn = get_class();
    }
    return new $cn($response);
}
```

Currently $cn contains class Bookmyroom and $response is object containing error

for e.g. class bookroom-

```
class Bookmyroom extends Error
{
   // contains some functions
}
```

Error Class:-

```
class Error extends Base
{
    public $response;

    public function __construct($response)
    {
        $this->_objectify($response->body);
    }

    public function _objectify($fields)
    {
        foreach ($fields as $key => $val) {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

Only the line

```
return new $cn($response);
```

in the first function

```
function CreateFormResponse();
```

throws 500 Internal Server Error - Bookmyroom

Thanx in advance...

Comment: having an error 500 it's not important: what is the error message?

Comment: this is the error stack:

500 Internal Server Error - Bookroom

Stack Trace

in /var/www/application/vendor/balanced/balanced/src/Balanced/Errors.php at line 35 -+
        else
            $cn = get_class();
        
        return new $cn($response);
    }
}

Comment: Have you 'error1', 'error2' and 'error3' classes?

Comment: This looks like a really confusing object design to me. Factory-style error creation (or something?), public methods prefixed with underscores, non-concrete properties instead of something `__get()`/`__set()` or `ArrayAccess` - it all just looks very confused and not well thought out.